# Office 365 Graph API not returning Inbox folder messages but am getting Sent Items and Deleted Items

Tags: c#, office365, office365api

I can't get Inbox messages to return when querying for "me/messages" via the C# nuget client but I can get messages from other folders.

```
client.Me.Messages.Request().Filter("createdDateTime gt 2017-08-01T15:50:36.00Z").OrderBy("createdDateTime").Expand("attachments").GetAsync()
```

For some reason this returns only messages from the "Sent Items", "Deleted Items" and "Conversations" folders. But I don't get anything from the Inbox folder.

What's weird is that I can query for the list of folders and expand Messages for each folder and there are messages appearing for the Inbox.

```
IUserMailFoldersCollectionPage foldersPage = await client.Me.MailFolders.Request().Expand("messages").GetAsync();
```

So how come the messages appear on the folder object for the Inbox but not when I query "me/messages"?

Answer (score 1):

According to your descriptions, I suppose you want to get the messages in the inbox folder by using the API:

`GET /users/{Garth-id | Garth-userPrincipalName}/messages`.

Base on my test, it will get all the messages in the signed-in user's mailbox. According to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/zh-cn/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages#response), The default page size for this request is 10 messages.

We can get the `parentFolderId` from the response, and then we can use the `parentFolderId` to request this API: `GET /users/{Garth-id | Garth-userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}` for getting the folder name.

There are two steps to check it whether the messages in the inbox folder will back.

1.We can increase the page size to get more messages, and please follow he code below:

```
var collectionMessagePage = await _serviceClient.Me.Messages.Request().Top(20).GetAsync();
```

2. We can get the folder id in the response, and use the `Folder ID` to compare with the ID of the inbox.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. I was already pulling the list of folders and then paging through the results for "me/messages" already using the NextPage token and comparing the parentFolderID but I wasn't getting anything from the Inbox. I will try specifying the actual user instead of just using "me/messages" and see if that helps.

Comment: Specifying the ID of the user didn't help. I ended up just looping thru the folders and querying each individually which isn't a very good solution as it requires a lot more requests.

Comment: Base my test, using "me/messages" will get all the messages, including the inbox folder.I think you can try a new email, then request "me/messages".